# Odd behaviour when re-rendering with defaultValue vs value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I noticed a very odd behaviour when it comes to `defaultValue`. When you re-render using `defaultValue` parts of it may not register the re-render and maintains the initial rendering of the state.

See pic: [image]

However switching from `defaultValue` to `value` fixes this issue.

This is both a heads up to other people who may be experiencing this issue and a question as to why this occurs.

The line of code that generates this:

```
      inner_array.push(
        <div key={j}>
          <input defaultValue={final_line} style={{ width: "100%" }} onClick={this.highlight} ></input>
        </div>)
```

This eventually gets `map`'d like this:

```
{Object.keys(data).map( (item, index) => (!item.match(/default/i)) ? <li key={index}>{item}</li> : "")}
```

**Extra information**

So the thing that causes the re-render is `setState`. I'm overriding a previous object with another object.

## Example

defaultValue and value in action:
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/74509/

Comment: My guess is that it may be related to your `key` prop being collided when you change the list of items. It's not recommended to use an array index as a key. Try to replace it to anything that is unique.

Comment: @AlexM Hmm, doesn't seem to be the case. What are the actual purpose of the keys anyway? They seem to function alright without them, I just add them in because the console throws a bit of a hissy fit if I don't

Comment: I checked your example. Actually, that was the case. I'll give you an explanation in a few minutes.

Comment: Here's an example with unique `key` prop: https://jsfiddle.net/b9qy7o3x/
Notice that the key now consists not only of index but also of object ID, which makes it unique.
I'll post more detailed answer soon

Comment: @AlexM that's interesting. Why doesn't something as simple as `"something"+index` work? I've updated the fiddle to show both defaultValue and normal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing about `defaultValue` property is that it only set to an input element when it's mounted.

In your example, you have two lists of elements, and you use an array index as a key. When you switch the source list (array or object, doesn't really matter becase you'll eventually map it to an array of elements),
some of your keys stay the same (index `0` and `1`), so React just **updates** those elements **instead of unmounting them and mounting the new ones**. And, as you know, `defaultValue` is only set once, when the element is being mounted. So changes to `defaultValue` do not take effect when the component updates.

To fix this issue, you need to force React to re-mount `<input>` instead of updating them. It can be done by making sure that the `key` props change when you switch the list.
I updated your example ( https://jsfiddle.net/b9qy7o3x/ ) so that it adds an ID of the list to the `key` prop, making it always unique.