# Unexpected behaviour when conditionally rendering the same input component with different defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

> **NOTE:** this question aims to understand why this code gives this behaviour, not what alternative code would give the desired one.

I have a custom component to represent a particular form field, and I wanted to conditionally render it with different props depending on conditions. In the real example, more props change between the cases, but I have distilled it to this minimal example below, see this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xkzywjvL/1/

```
function DummyInput({defaultValue}) {
console.log(defaultValue)
    return (
  <input defaultValue={defaultValue}/>
  )
}

function Picker({setContentOption})
{
  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    setContentOption(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
      <select onChange={handleOptionChange}>
        <option value="content-A">content-A</option>
        <option value="content-B">content-B</option>
        <option value="content-C">content-C</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      )
}

function App() {
const [contentOption, setContentOption] = React.useState('content-A')
let inputField = null

if (contentOption === 'content-A'){
    inputField = <DummyInput defaultValue="A"></DummyInput>
}
else if (contentOption === 'content-B'){
    inputField = <DummyInput defaultValue="B"></DummyInput>
}
else if (contentOption === 'content-C'){
    inputField = <DummyInput defaultValue="C"></DummyInput>
}

return (
    <div>
      <div>See that the console prints three times, meaning that
      code is executed in all three versions, but only the third
      re-renders the component</div>
      <br/>
      <Picker setContentOption={setContentOption}/>
      <br/>
      <div>Does not work - if / else statement in function body</div>
      {inputField}
      
      <div>Does not work - inline if else statement</div>
      {(contentOption === 'content-A') && (
      <DummyInput defaultValue="A"></DummyInput>
      ) || (contentOption === 'content-B') && (
      <DummyInput defaultValue="B"></DummyInput>
      ) || (contentOption === 'content-C') && (<DummyInput defaultValue="C"></DummyInput>)}
      
      <div>Works - three separate inline if statements</div>
      {contentOption === 'content-A' && <DummyInput defaultValue="A"></DummyInput>}
      {contentOption === 'content-B' && <DummyInput defaultValue="B"></DummyInput>}    
      {contentOption === 'content-C' && <DummyInput defaultValue="C"></DummyInput>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

The app renders a form field component `DummyInput` with a `defaultValue` that changes depending on state `contentOption` from the parent `App` component (in the real example there are more differences that one prop). I expected the `defaultValue` to change based on the state, regardless of the conditional rendering method used.

I originally assigned the component to a variable `inputField` in an if - else statement, but realised that it did not update the component. Instead, if I use three separate `&&` to render conditionally, the components do update as in the example, but not if I use an inline if-else.

By putting a console.log statement in DummyInput I can see that even though the component is not re-rendering with the updated defaultValue, the code inside the component is being executed.

What is the reason for this behaviour? The reason why I want to know is that I might be inadvertedly doing something similar elsewhere without noticing.

### Similar previous questions

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990777/odd-behaviour-when-re-rendering-with-defaultvalue-vs-value) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886119/react-input-defaultvalue-re-rendering), and if I add a "key" to the `DummyInput`, it works. However, I don't understand why this is needed outside of a `map` function, nor why three separate inline if statements work.

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultValue` is changing in all cases. You don't see it because once the input is rendered the first time it now has a `value`, and changing the `defaultValue` after that does not change the `value` of that input. It works for 3rd case because in that case it is destroying the component and creating a new one everytime.

If you type something in the inputs and then change the dropdown, you'll see that the first two values remain, the third one loses your input.

It should become apparent if you change to placeholder. `<input placeholder={defaultValue}/>`

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense, and it only happens for the `inputValue`, and not other properties. However, I still don't fully understand why React "thinks" that the component is the same with the regular if / else, but not with the three separate inline statements. It's not the DOM position, since it's the same for all three implementations. I see what you mean by the destroying of the componet, but I would have never thought this would be different from a regular if / else.

Do you know if other html attributes have similar behaviours?

Comment: It is the same component, your code is compiled by react into js, and since it's all within the same {} it deals with it "smartly" when compiling. The `defaultValue` has a side effect in a way that it sets the `value`, if a `value` is not provided.